# Mongodb Node.js Document get amount of writes of N last days

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Im trying to make an activity monitoring system

My goal is it to have an array of days and how many times a document has been written to or updated

How can I do ?

Comment: Perhaps if you show how you store times in a document when it _"has been written to or updated"_, an aggregation pipeline could be suggested.